# Calculate $\lim _{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{3x^2+7}{2x^2+4x}\right)^{3x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate $$\lim _{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{3x^2+7}{2x^2+4x}\right)^{3x}$$

I see that the sequence grows without a bound so I think that

$$\lim _{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{3x^2+7}{2x^2+4x}\right)^{3x}=\infty$$

but how can I prove it in the right way

Comment: factor the dominant powers of $x$ you get $\sim(3/2)^{3x}$

Comment: Just in order to avoid misunderstandings, with $\infty$ do you mean positive infinity?

Comment: @egreg yes i think it supposed to be $\to \infty+$ then its correct

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

Assuming $x \to +\infty$:

Note that your expression inside the parenthesis goes to $\frac{3}{2}$. To show this, factor out $x^2$ in both the numerator and the denominator. Therefore, your limit becomes the same $(\frac{3}{2})^{+\infty}=+\infty$

If $x \to -\infty$, the limit becomes $0$, because using the same logic, you factor out $x^2$ in the numerator and the denominator and then you can give the minus sign of infinity to the expression inside the parenthesis and it becomes $((\frac{3}{2})^{-1})^{+\infty}=(\frac{2}{3})^{+\infty}=0$

Therefore, for $x \to \infty$ the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Collect $x^2$ inside the brackets:

$$\left(\frac{x^2\left(3 + \frac{7}{x^2}\right)}{x^2\left(2 + \frac{4}{x}\right)}\right)^{3x}$$

Now $x^2$ terms do simplify each other and you know that as $x \to\infty$ then $4/x$ and $7/x^2$ go to $0$. Hence you're left with

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{3x}$$

Which goes to $\infty$... **Wrong**

The limit doesn't exist, unless you specify the sign of the infinity.

Indeed :

for $x\to +\infty$ the limit is $+\infty$

for $x\to -\infty$ the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$, real, and $x > 8$.

Consider the limit $x \rightarrow +\infty$.

Numerator : $3x^2 +7 > 3x^2$.

Denominator : $2x^2 +4x < 2x^2 + (1/2)x^2$, for $x>8.$

Then

$f(x):= \Big(\dfrac{3x^2 +7}{2x^2+4x}\Big)^{3x} >$

$\Big(\dfrac{3x^2}{(5/2)x^2}\Big)^{3x} =\Big(\Big(\dfrac{6}{5}\Big)^3\Big)^x$.

Let $b:= \Big(\dfrac{6}{5} \Big)^3 >1.$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}f(x) \ge \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} b^x = +\infty.$

Note: For $b>1$ : $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} b^x = +\infty.$

Comment: This is actually wrong. You should specify the sign of the infinite, because the limit doesn't exist...

Comment: Henry. Thanks for your suggestion.